# My Flutter is not connected to Cloud Firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

My Flutter is not able to connect to my Cloud Firestore. Everything works fine, I can register, I can login, and the user is saved in the auth in Firebase. But the Cloud Firestore is not recieving any data from the registration_page.dart

**My code to add the user to firestore**

```
// Adding User to Cloud Firestore
  CollectionReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');

  Future<void> addUser() {
    return users
        .add({
          'email': email,
          'password': password,
          'confirmPassword': confirmPassword
        })
        .then((value) => print('User Added'))
        .catchError((error) => print('Failed to Add user: $error'));
  }
```

**This is my onPressed for the signUpButton**

```
onPressed: () {
// Validate returns true if the form is valid, otherwise false.
                if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                  setState(() {
                    email = emailController.text;
                    password = passwordController.text;
                    confirmPassword = confirmPasswordController.text;
                    passwordRegistration();
                    addUser();
                    clearText();
                  });
                }
              },
```

**This is my full code of registration_page.dart**

```
// ignore_for_file: prefer_const_constructors, avoid_print

import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:list_list_2/constants/color_constant.dart';
import 'package:list_list_2/page/login/login_page.dart';

class RegistrationPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const RegistrationPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<RegistrationPage> createState() => _RegistrationPageState();
}

class _RegistrationPageState extends State<RegistrationPage> {
  //Form Key
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  var email = "";
  var password = "";
  var confirmPassword = "";

  final emailController = TextEditingController();
  final passwordController = TextEditingController();
  final confirmPasswordController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Clean up the controller when the widget is disposed.
    emailController.dispose();
    passwordController.dispose();
    confirmPasswordController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  clearText() {
    emailController.clear();
    passwordController.clear();
    confirmPasswordController.clear();
  }

  passwordRegistration() async {
    if (password == confirmPassword) {
      try {
        UserCredential userCredential = await FirebaseAuth.instance
            .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
        print(userCredential);
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
          SnackBar(
            backgroundColor: kSoftLimeGreen,
            content: Text(
              "Registered Successfully. Please Login..",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
            ),
          ),
        );
        Navigator.pushReplacement(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => LoginPage(),
          ),
        );
      } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
        if (e.code == 'weak-password') {
          print("Password Provided is too Weak");
          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
            SnackBar(
              backgroundColor: lightOrange,
              content: Text(
                "Password Provided is too Weak",
                style: GoogleFonts.dongle(fontSize: 18.0, color: blackColor),
              ),
            ),
          );
        } else if (e.code == 'email-already-in-use') {
          print("Account Already exists");
          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
            SnackBar(
              backgroundColor: lightOrange,
              content: Text(
                "Account Already exists",
                style: GoogleFonts.dongle(fontSize: 18.0, color: blackColor),
              ),
            ),
          );
        }
      }
    } else {
      print("Password and Confirm Password doesn't match");
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(
          backgroundColor: lightOrange,
          content: Text(
            "Password and Confirm Password doesn't match",
            style: GoogleFonts.dongle(fontSize: 16.0, color: blackColor),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
  }

  // Adding User to Cloud Firestore
  CollectionReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');

  Future<void> addUser() {
    return users
        .add({
          'email': email,
          'password': password,
          'confirmPassword': confirmPassword
        })
        .then((value) => print('User Added'))
        .catchError((error) => print('Failed to Add user: $error'));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //Email Field
    final emailField = TextFormField(
      autofocus: false,
      controller: emailController,
      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
      validator: (value) {
        if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
          return 'Please Enter Email';
        } else if (!value.contains('@')) {
          return 'Please Enter Valid Email';
        }
        return null;
      },
      textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.mail),
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 15, 20, 15),
        hintText: "Email",
        border: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        ),
      ),
    );
    //Password Field
    final passwordField = TextFormField(
      autofocus: false,
      controller: passwordController,
      obscureText: true,
      validator: (value) {
        if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
          return 'Please Enter Password';
        }
        return null;
      },
      textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.vpn_key),
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 15, 20, 15),
        hintText: "Password",
        border: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        ),
      ),
    );
    //Confirm Password
    final confirmPasswordField = TextFormField(
      autofocus: false,
      controller: confirmPasswordController,
      obscureText: true,
      validator: (value) {
        if (confirmPasswordController.text != passwordController.text) {
          return "Password Don't Match!";
        }
        return null;
      },
      textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.vpn_key),
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 15, 20, 15),
        hintText: "Confirm Password",
        border: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        ),
      ),
    );
    //Sign Up Button
    final signUpButton = Material(
      elevation: 5,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
      child: Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        height: 60,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
          gradient: LinearGradient(
            colors: const [kDarkModerateCyan, kModerateCyan],
            begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
            end: Alignment.centerRight,
          ),
        ),
        child: Material(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
          color: Colors.transparent,
          child: Center(
            child: MaterialButton(
              child: Text(
                "SignUp",
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: GoogleFonts.dongle(
                  fontSize: 28,
                  color: defaultColor,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 10, 20, 15),
              minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              onPressed: () {
                // Validate returns true if the form is valid, otherwise false.
                if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                  setState(() {
                    email = emailController.text;
                    password = passwordController.text;
                    confirmPassword = confirmPasswordController.text;
                    passwordRegistration();
                    addUser();
                    clearText();
                  });
                }
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
    //Reset Button
    final resetButton = Material(
      elevation: 5,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
      child: Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        height: 60,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
          color: greyColor,
        ),
        child: Material(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
          color: Colors.transparent,
          child: Center(
            child: MaterialButton(
              child: Text(
                "Reset",
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: GoogleFonts.dongle(
                  fontSize: 28,
                  color: defaultColor,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 10, 20, 15),
              minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              onPressed: () => {clearText()},
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: whiteColor,
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        elevation: 0,
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.arrow_back,
            color: kVeryDarkCyan,
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            //passing this to our root
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
          },
        ),
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Material(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(55),
                  color: kDarkModerateCyan,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(36.0),
                    child: Form(
                      key: _formKey,
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 180,
                            child: SvgPicture.asset(
                              "assets/logo.svg",
                              fit: BoxFit.contain,
                            ),
                          ),
                          emailField,
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 15,
                          ),
                          passwordField,
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 15,
                          ),
                          confirmPasswordField,
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 15,
                          ),
                          signUpButton,
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 15,
                          ),
                          resetButton,
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 15,
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: This is my firestore image]

And this is my GitHub https://github.com/MonsterEat90/List-List

Comment: "But the Cloud Firestore is recieving any data from the registration_page.dart" Is it receiving data or not?

Comment: sorry, mistype. let me edit it first